# Design: Bind unmarshalled JAXB objects to JavaFX controls

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jaxb, javafx

I have troubles to approach my goal in a proper, MVC kind of way: A JavaFX application that can unmarshall tickets from an XML file with JAXB and display one of one-to-many tickets from the xml file (selected with a combobox or paginator) in some textbox controls.

MainWindowController (and fxml file):

```
public class MainWindowController {
    // contains all the fxml controls
    private TicketAnalyzer ticketAnalyzer = new TicketAnalyzer();
    private List<TicketType> tickets = new ArrayList<TicketType>();

    @FXML
    private TextField txtNr1;
    //....
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNr5;

    private IntegerProperty nr1;
    //....
    private IntegerProperty nr5;

    @FXML
    protected void initialize(){     
        nr1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        bind();
    }

    private void bind(){
        txtCurWinNr1.textProperty().bindBidirectional(nr1, new NumberStringConverter());
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnEvaluateAction(ActionEvent event) {
        List<TicketType> tickets = ticketAnalyzer.evaluate(txtXMLPath.getText());
    if(tickets != null)
        this.tickets = tickets;

    updateTicket();
    }

    private void updateTicket(){
        if(this.tickets != null && this.tickets.size() > 0){
             nr1.set(tickets.get(0).getPlays().get(0).getNumbers().getNumber().get(0));         

        }
    }   
}
```

Then the ´ticketAnalyzer´ class:

```
public class TicketAnalyzer {

    private String xsdPath;

    public void loadXSD(String xsdPath){
    this.xsdPath = xsdPath;
}

    public void evaluate(String xmlPath){
        if(xsdPath.length() <= 0)
            return;

        if(!XMLValidator.validateXMLSchema(xsdPath, xmlPath)){
            System.out.println("THE XML file "+xmlPath+" is not valide agains "+xsdPath);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        JAXBContext jc;
        try {
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("jaxb.ticket");
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            Source source = new StreamSource(new java.io.FileInputStream(xmlPath));

            JAXBElement<TicketsType> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source,TicketsType.class);
            TicketsType ticketsType = root.getValue();
            List<TicketType> tickets = ticketsType.getTicket();
            for (TicketType ticket : tickets) displayTicket(ticket);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When I evaluate a new XML file, the local tickets List in the controller is updated and when I change the property value, the new value is shown in the textfield, as desired.

I am very unsure though if that approach is correct. Well it's working but it feels kind of not right. Especially because I will have to do this with many numbers and have to be able to select the ticket (right now, the 0 index is hard coded) and even a selection of the play inside of the ticket.

Isn't there a more beautiful way? I'm very new to the whole Java and JavaFX world.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Since you don't show your model class(es) and their associated JAXB annotations, I can't say for sure if what you are doing is correct. It sounds like what you are doing is right, if by what I read here is, you are binding your model-level classes to the XML schema, such that when you unmarshal your objects, the UI is updated "automatically" because it is designed to react to changes in your underlying model objects. If that's what you are doing (or trying to do), then I'd say you're on the right track.

Comment: Thank you - Ryan. I actually thought of my JAXB generated classes as my model classes. What I do not like, is that I have to work with IntegerProperties. My post is quite simplified; In the end I will have like 20 Integer properties that I bind to different member variables of my List<TicketType> tickets. Isn't it possible to use this List as my "property" and bind controls to elements of this property, like tickets.getPlays().get(0), so that when the List gets updated, the controls will get updated? right now, I have to assign elements of my ticket list to properties.

Comment: I would say yes, as you could always implement the `Property` interface (or extend the `SimpleListProperty` and create a property for your List, rather than for each individual element. I've never done that, so I don't know how complicated it will be, but as long as your controls are set up to observe your List (Tickets) property properly, then that should buy you what you want.